# How to print a double array?

Tags: java, arrays, double, decimal

I need to print this double array but I keep getting an error at the last line with "index" and it says "cannot convert double to int".

```
double[] i1 = new double[] {0.15, 0.875, 0.375};

Arrays.sort(i1);
System.out.print("1st array : ");

for(double index=0; index < i1.length ; index++)
    System.out.print("  "  + i1[index]);
```

Answer (score 3):

A `double` array still has `int` indices (just like any type of array), so `index` should be an `int` :

```
for(int index=0; index < i1.length ; index++)
    System.out.print("  "  + i1[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Alternatively](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(double[])), Arrays.toString(array).replaceAll(", ", "YourFavoriteSeparator")